# Default program not listed in windows10 settings

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code, file-extension, default-settings

> TL;DR: read only bold text + check pictures.

I was trying to **change .txt files default program to visual studio code**,
the problem is, that when I open settings in windows 10 and try to change it there,
**visual studio code is not listed in the default programs** and there is **no browse button**,
so that I could pick any program I want via the path to it.
[image]

I have also tried to **change the default app in *right MB -> open with -> choose another app***, but no luck, **there was no permanent option**.

[image]

How are you supposed to change the default program than?

Comment: Don't you have in the "Open with" dialog the check-box "Always use this app to open .txt f‌iles"?

Comment: @harrymc as you could have seen in the picture, no I don't, the option is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was really no checkbox for "Always use this app to open .txt files" on your "Choose another app" menu, you might have luck changing your default app settings - which you can either search for on your Windows 10 or:

> - Go to **Control Panel**

- Click **Default Programs**
- Click **Set your default programs**
- Click **Choose default apps by file type**
- Scroll down to **.txt**
- Change your application to **Visual Studio Code**

If that doesn't work, you should also be able to do so from command-line using the `ftype` and `assoc` commands:

```
ftype txtfile="C:\Path\To\Visual Studio Code.exe"
assoc .txt=txtfile
```

Reference: [ftype](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html), [assoc](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html)

Comment: The problem is, that on updated version of windows10, this does not work anymore, the control pannel will just send you back to new windows10 settings

Comment: I edited the answer a little; so are you able to change it but it's not sticking? or are you unable to get to that "choose default apps by file type" screen?

Comment: the command line method worked, but in control panel, under default programs, set your default programs will send you to windows settings, where, when i go to choose default apps by file and find .txt, there isn't visual studio code in options and no browse button so that I could add it, you can see that from the 1st picture.

Comment: interesting; glad the command-line worked though!