# Add an arbitrary EXE to the Music player default apps list

Tags: windows-10

I changed the EXE name of Windows Media Player from wmplayer.exe to wmplayer2.exe to use [DPI compatibility settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1644181/override-high-dpi-settings-for-windows-media-player/1644194#1644194). I can edit the shortcut of WMP and launch it directly, but doubling clicking a music file does not work any more. To fix that, I want to set wmplayer2.exe as the default "Music player" in Settings -> Apps -> Default apps -> Music player.

The problem is that if I click the "Choose a default" button, it shows only a few applications, search Windows store, but not a browse for a file button. I think I need to add an arbitrary EXE to that list by telling that the EXE is a music application. But how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1458394/855367 (the command line part).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks, but thay seems to be a way to associate a specific extension to an EXE. If I use that way, I have to repeat it for all audio file extensions. FireFox and VLC somehow already shown up in the list, so there should be a way to add my EXE there, shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that file associations would be a problem with my file copy approach. Adding the copy as a registered media player would be fairly painful, involving duplicating a bunch of Registry keys. I edited my answer to your other question with an alternative approach that modifies the original `wmplayer.exe`.